# Alembic migrate as_uuid for UUIDField

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to migrate a SQLAlchemy model (using Flask-SQLAlchemy if that helps). I use a model that looks like this:

```py
class Model:
    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True))

# With an occasional foreign key
class Model1:
    db.column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey("model.uuid"), nullable=False)
```

I found it easier to use `as_uuid=False`, but alembic does not automatically migrate this for us. What are the alembic commands I should write to get this working?

Comment: Are you talking about a migration using Alembic's `--autogenerate` feature?